# Can I use a different type of bolt for awning?

Tags: installation, bolts

I got a light plastic awning from amazon. It only has 3.4 pounds. The size are 30"x40". Now I want to install it over the front door.

[image: 1]

The package comes out a set of bolts(The size is marked as M10).

[image: 2]

However I heard that this kind of bolt is permanently positioned. In other word, it can't easily removed.
If the awning is damaged or I want to sell the property in the future, I have to uninstall the awning, then it becomes a problem.

So I am wondering is that possible to replace the bolts with other types which can be easily removed?

Comment: These are the types of bolts the manufacturer recommends to ensure that this awning doesn't fall off the wall and injure somebody or damage something. Using other bolts could be cause for your insurance company to deny a claim if something bad were to happen.

Comment: If you want recommendations for alternative fasteners then you need to know/inform us of the structure that you will be fastening the awning to. **I.E**. What kind of wall is it and how is it constructed, If it is wood framed construction will the mounting hole positions line up with wall studs or cavities in the wall.

Comment: It's brick wall.

Comment: I would not mount an awning into a brick veneer, only into concrete block or wall framing. The moment arm on an awning is substantial, and the pulling force is several times the weight put on the awning. Snow loads are the issue, not the weight of the awning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That type of bolt is made for use in brick or concrete. You would drill a hole just large enough for the sleeve to slide into. When tightening the bolt in place the sleeve crinkles at the end this tightly jamming the sleeve against the edges of the hole.

You can still remove the bolt leaving the sleeve in the hole. Even if you were able to remove the sleeve you would still have the hole left so it should be of little consequence if the sleeve is left behind.

Comment: To further this, if necessary, you could fill the hole inside the sleeve with something (like a splash of mortar) to pretty it up.

Comment: How deep should I drill? Same as the length of the bolt?

Comment: Your hole should be a little deeper than the anchor so as you drive the bolt in it has some room to go in and does not hit the back of the hole. Use a shop vac to vacuum any brick dust  left behind in the hole. ( *or a can compressed air with the little red tube on the nozzle to try and blow it out*. )  Wear eye protection and a mask. You will need a masonry bit of the appropriate size for your anchor.

Comment: You may want to check first if you Can  separate the  bolt from the anchor if you unscrew it. If not then it may be a one piece unit, usually not but i have seen some that are. If removal is important then you can find alternative anchors for masonry in the anchor section of the hardware store.

Comment: Follow up: The thing is that I picked a brick in the playground and tried drill a hole on it for practice, then the brick broken(spitted into two rather than a hole). I worried about it.

Comment: @Hello, post another question

Comment: @Hello - Bricks are prone to break when trying to drill just one out on its own. If you use proper drilling equipment to drill a hole into a brick that is captures top/bottom/left/right in a solid wall you should have success without the brick cracking.